# How to check if there is already a click/event associated to an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

lets say I have

```
function trigger(){

    $('a.pep').each(function(){
            $('a.pep').click(function(){
            console.log($(this).val());
        });
    });
}
function push(){
    $('body').append('<a class="pep">hey mate i have no trigger yet</a>');
    trigger();  //now i do but the others have duplicated trigger
}
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('a.push').click(function(){
        push();
     });
});
```

So it seems that the click event is being applied twice/+ because the console.log is lauched more than once by click

How can i prevent this?

Comment: Note that you're using a useless anonymous function. `$('a.push').click(push);` does the same thing.

Comment: ha! thanks! i actually thought about it while typing

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that you call `$('a.pep').click()` lots of times. (In fact, you bind as many click handlers as there are matching elements to *each* element. And then you do it again every time one of them is clicked.)

You should lever the DOM event bubbling model to handle this.  jQuery helps you with the [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on) method:

```
$(document.body).on('click', 'a.pep', function() {
    console.log('element clicked');
    $(document.body).append('<a class="pep">Click handlers handled automatically</a>');
});
```

[See a working jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/neLQN/)

Note that I have removed the `val` call, because `a` elements can't have a value... Note also that the `on` method is introduced in jQuery 1.7; before that, use [`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate):

```
$(document.body).delegate('a.pep', 'click', function() {
```

Comment: @Manuel Indeed, and I just edited to note that and to offer an alternative.

Comment: i should go for the delegate? (need support from 1.4 Jquery)

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet Yes, for 1.4 use `delegate`.

Comment: delegate was 1.4.2, so if you can use that then do, otherwise it'll be live or custom event bubbling. If all of your links are in a common container that does not change you can specify that instead of document.body as the initial selector so the event does not bubble so far up.

Answer (score 5):

Small change to your trigger function is all you need. Just unbind the click event before binding to ensure that it is never added more than once. Also, you don't need to use each when binding events, it will add the event to each item automatically.

```
function trigger(){        
    $('a.pep').unbind('click').click(function() {
        console.log($(this).val());
    });
}
```

Comment: not tested but that seems to solve my problem. @lonesomeday how not efficient would you call this??? considering maximum 10-15 .pep elements

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet It's still dozens of unnecessary selections, and far more complex code than is necessary.

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet With only 10-15 elements it probably won't be noticable, but lonesomedays answer would be better and require less code.

Answer (score 1):

You can check using `data('events')` on any element if the required event is attached or not. For example to check if `click` event is attached or not try this.

```
if(!$('a.pep').data('events').click){
   $('a.pep').click(function(){
      console.log($(this).val());
   });
}
```

Comment: Note that `.data("events")` is deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

you should use [jQuery live here](http://api.jquery.com/live/) because you add DOM elements dynamicly and you want them to have the same `click` behaviour

```
function push(){
    $('body').append('<a class="pep">hey mate i have no trigger yet</a>');
}
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('a.push').click(function(){
        push();
     });
     $('a.pep').live('click', function(){
        console.log($(this).val());
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
if($('a.pep').data('events').click) {
   //do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think if you use live() event you dont need to make function

```
$('a.pep').live('click', function(){
    console.log($(this).val());
});
```